# Вопрос по отношениям Laravel постов у пользователей

Tags: laravel

```
    $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);

    $collection = [];

    foreach ($user->posts as $post) {
            $collection[] = $post;
    }

    return $collection;
```

Добрый день, есть рабочий код получения постов у пользователя, думаю это не совсем правильно, можно ли упростить запись используя with или еще как

Связь

```
public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post', 'user_posts');
    }
```

Comment: `$user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);` - можно проще: `$user = Auth::user();`. Вместо цикла: `return $user->posts->toArray();`. А можно без `toArray`, так как возвращается Collection, по которой можно проходить также циклом.

Answer (score 1):

`with` - это **Eager loading** (жадная загрузка).

Данный запрос загрузит пользователя и все его записи.

```
$user = User::with('posts')->find(Auth::user()->id);
```

Если пользователь вам не нужен. Запрашивайте только посты.

```
$posts = Post::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

Если нужно привести результат к массиву, используйте `$posts->toArray()`.